# How to combine two json key-value pairs into one in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: json, azure, logic, logical-operators, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to conmbine two key-value pairs of JSON into one in Azure Logic Apps.

When I use this code in my compose action:

```
"Compose": {
            "inputs": {
                "financelInformation": "@body('HTTP')['currency']",
                "amount": "@body('HTTP')['amount']
            }
}
```

it will create the following JSON output:

```
{"financelInformation":"eur", "amount": "499"}
```

However what I'm trying to achieve is the following output:

```
{"financelInformation":"499 eur"}
```

I've tried this so far:

```
"Compose": {
            "inputs": {
                "financelInformation": "@body('HTTP')['amount']['currency']",        
                "financelInformation": "@body('HTTP')['amount'] '-' ['currency']",        
            }
}
```

The above 2 attempts did not work, hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the answer you want? (I post two screenshots below, but I initialize two variables which are different from your http body, I think you just need to type a space between the two values)

[image]

[image]

**update**

I tested it again with the value from http action, I got two values from a http action. The code in my compose action is as follows:

```
"inputs": {
     "financelInformation": "@{body('HTTP')['id']} @{body('HTTP')['name']}"
}
```

You can take a look as a reference.